# How do I change the size of my article depending on an image?

Tags: css, html, image, tags

I've just created some articles in an HTML5 file. Those articles contain images. The articles also have a border at the bottom.
Now I have this problem that whenever you re-size your window to make it larger, the images go outside the border. I want the border to re-size with the image.

Here's an example of how an article looks like in my page:

```
<article>
  <p>
    <img image />
  </p>
  <p>
    text
  </p>
</article>
```

The p-tag with the image inside floats left, the p-tag with text floats right next to it.

To be more clear: I want the article tag to resize to the height of the image.

Comment: Can you post your CSS and/or a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: My question would become unclear. It's way too much CSS and Html. All I want is a tag above to resize with a tag below. So I want the height of the article tag to resize to the height of the p or img-tag.

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping your images in `p` tags either. Lemme guess, is this WP?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's a WP?

Comment: Post relevant HTML and CSS. How are your articles laid out? What styles are being applied to your `article` and `p` and `img`?

Comment: The articles itself don't really have any specific css bound to them (except for a fixed height, because I can't find any other way to make the border below the image). The image and text are floated left for the first, third, fifth... article, floated right for the second, fourth, sixth... article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, without seeing a working example or any of your CSS, but adding `overflow: auto` to the `article` element will cause it to contain its floated children:

```
article  {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Example that may or may not relate to the CSS we can't see: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/opnfG

Comment: Technical explanation is that it creates a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)

Comment: Ohh, great! I'm new to html, so I didn't know about this. This is going to be useful in many ways! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: No problem. Please do read this, however, if you'd like to avoid all the requests for better examples in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve